# Is there a method in ArcObjects that is equivalent to ArcPy's: SelectLayerByLocation_management?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcobjects

I have 2 `IFeatureClass` and I want to do an INTERSECT between the two.  What is the best way to do this from ArcObjects?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *intersect*... do you want to find overlapping/intersecting features from one feature class or clip the geometries?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you mean a feature selection (select by location) and not a geoprocessing intersect then I think you want [ISpatialFilter](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000083n000000). This allows the same actions as SelectLayerByLocation including overlap type options and attribute queries.